# Add a kableExtra table to a patchwork grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, kable, patchwork

I would like to add a table that was formatted via the kableExtra package to a patchwork grid of ggplots and pictures. At the moment I have no idea how to continue. I am able to convert my table that I create via CreateTableOne() to a tibble and add that to the patchwork grid, but the result is not even close to the qulity of a kableExtra table.

Thank you very much in advance!

BR,

Answer (score 0):

You could create an empty space using `plot_spacer` and at your Kable table as an image on that empty space next to your plot. I am using `mtcars` dataset as an example. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(png)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) 
t1 <- kable(mtcars[1:10, c('mpg', 'disp')]) %>% 
  kable_styling() %>%
  save_kable('table1.png')
your_table <- readPNG('~/Downloads/table1.png', native = TRUE)
p1 + plot_spacer() + inset_element(p = your_table, left =0, bottom = 0, right = 1, top = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>